# Modbus sniffing using python

Tags: python, serial-communication, modbus, sniffing

I have 2 devices communicating with each other using Modbus and I would like to sniff this communication line using Python for logging purposes. I have connected my computer to the communication bus via a Modbus dongle, but I don't know how I can actually read the data.

I have used Pymodbus before, but I don't think that would work in this case since it only allows for master or slave devices (as far as I know)

Are there any other libraries that I can use for my purpose? Would it be possible for me to implement something like a read only socket on the COM port that doesn't interfere with existing communication on the bus?

Thank you!

Comment: Essentially it's a basic serial connection in the foundation, if you can setup a connection that doesn't interfere with the transmission between A and B you could just read the data as raw data and parse it. Yes normally pymodbus will be either a slave or a master and thus parse data accordingly, but you basically want `tcpdump` but for serial data? There for some parsing of your own will be done after dumping the raw serial data. If possible just use http://freecode.com/projects/linuxserialsniffer/

Answer (score -1):

You can try a MODBUS simulator like [this](http://www.modbustools.com/modbus_poll.html) one: It has an option to see the activity on the bus.

If you want to use another python MODBUS I recommend using [modbus_tk](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk). It has an example on how to create an MODBUS simulator. But to be able sniff the packets sent to other devices you will need to do some modifications to disable the automatic response.

If the only thing you want to do is to see the activity on the bus I recommend the first option.

I hope this helps you.

[Edit]:To be more specific you will need to download the following software : **Modbus Poll** - **MODBUS slave simulator**(which works on Windows) and plug your MODBUS dongle in the port you intend to use. After you do all the settings for the serial communications go to the *Display* tab and click on *Communication*. You will be able to see the traffic on the line.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14126442)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will try to improve my posts